# Getting currently iterated data table row in p:fileUpload listener method

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, datatable

I'm using `<p:fileUpload>` in a `<p:dataTable>`. Upload works fine, but I'd like to know the currently iterated row in listener method so that I can update the right row in my DB.

XHTML:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{doorBean.handleFileUpload}"
    mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" update="messages"
    sizeLimit="3000000"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
```

Bean:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    this.file = event.getFile();
    ...
}
```

How can I achieve this? Can I pass an additional parameter to the bean?

Comment: That depends upon how you represent DB rows on the view? Are you for example, using some iterator components like `<p/h:dataTable>`? If yes then, you should be able to pass a row identifier completely independent/regardless of `<p:fileUpload>`.

Comment: the `fileupload` is a child of `datatable`

Comment: Since you are using PrimeFaces, `datatable` in essence, should be more likely `<p:dataTable>`. `<p:dataTable>` can give you back a model object representing the target row (which you want to edit/update). Therefore, while performing an update operation (among CRUD), there is no point to pass an independent (scalar) value representing a row identifier. You can use the entire model object along with `InputStream` or `byte[]` to update that row (you should be able to do this in an action(Listener) method). Don't you? What is the point to pass a value in conjunction with `<p:fileUpload>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item" ...>
```

either grab the currently iterated row from EL in the listener method:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Item item = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{item}", Item.class);
```

or simply move the listener method from the `Bean` to the `Item`:

```
 <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{item.handleFileUpload}" ... />
```